# How to swap zoom shared screen with videos side-by-side mode?

Tags: zoom.us

In Zoom's side-by-side mode, the shared screen is to the left of all the webcam videos. Is there a way to swap this so that the shared screen is on the right?

My own webcam is to the left of my screen so it is more natural that when I am talking to someone during a shared session, my eyes are more directed towards the camera.